# Subscriber specific ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

So I have the following snippet:

```
%%[
  var @lookupValue
  var @url

  set @lookupValue = "1"

  set @url = Lookup("Subscription_release","UnsubscribeUrl","ConnectId", @lookupValue)
]%%

Lookup value is %%=v(@lookupValue)=%% and url is %%=v(@url)=%%
```

And when trying to test it I get the error:

> Emails containing subscriber specific AMPscript cannot be sent without
>   selecting a subscriber in Test Send. Remove the AMPscript from the
>   email or select a subscriber to preview and test send.

I'm wondering, first, **what is *subscriber-specific AMPScript*** since I haven't been able to find anything about it in docs or Google with a quick scan and, secondly, **which part is the subscriber-specific?**

Comment: I'd stay away from Test Sends in general.  Going the route of Send Preview for one-off testing is better.

Comment: What you have should work.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs what's up with test sends? Do they usually fail? Is there any docs which state what kind of Ampscript can't be used in test sends without referencing a subscriber?

Comment: Test sends don't work with AMPScript.  It's better to create a test/seed audience and do a Guided Send to it or send a test from Send Preview